# Taylor expansion of $\tan x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

I was trying to get the first 4 terms of the expansion,

anyway this is what I got,

$(\tan x)'=\sec^2x$

$(\tan x)''=(\sec^2x)'=(\frac{1}{cos^{2}x})'=-2(\frac{1}{\cos^{3}x})(-\sin x)=2\frac{\sin x}{cos^{3}x}$

$(\tan x)'''=(2\frac{\sin x}{\cos^{3}x})'= \frac{\cos^{4}x-(-\sin x)(\sin x)3\cos^{2} x}{\cos^{6}x} = $ $ \frac{\cos^{4}x+(\sin^{2}x)3\cos^{2}x }{\cos^{6}x} = $
$ \frac{\cos^{2}+6\sin^2x) }{\cos^{6}x} = $  $ \frac{2+4\sin^2x) }{\cos^{4}x}  $

Now doing the Taylor series with x$_0$=0 $\implies$ tan x=0+x+0x$^2$+2x$^3$/3! . why is it wrong?

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong? The first two nonzero terms of the Maclaurin expansion of $\tan$ are indeed: $$\tan(x)\approx x+\frac{2}{3!}x^3=x+\frac{1}{3}x^3$$

Comment: wolfram alpha makes it differernt so i thought it is wrong(i just dint transform 3! to six, so just mt bad)

Comment: You may use the equation $y'=1+y^2$, then differentiate as many times as necessary: $y''=2yy'=2y(1+y^2)=2y+2y^3$, etc. Each time you get a polynomial in $y$ on the RHS, to get the value of the $n$th derivative at zero, just replace $y$ with $0$ as $\tan0=0$. Cumbersome, but very straightforward, and even easy to program.

Comment: WA gives a Taylor series that starts $x+\frac13x^3$. I think what's confused you is you expected their $n$th term shown to be your $n$th term, but WA doesn't show terms whose coefficient is $0$. $\tan x$ is odd.

Comment: Easier way:$$\tan x=x\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x}}{\cos x}=x\frac{1-\frac{1}{3!}x^2+\frac{1}{5!}(x^2)^2-\cdots}{1-\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{4!}(x^2)^2-\cdots}=x\left(1+\frac13x^2+\frac{2}{15}(x^2)^2+\cdots\right)$$

Comment: can i know how you divide each term?

Comment: You don't divide, you multiply: $\dfrac{A}{1-\epsilon}=A\cdot(1+\epsilon+\epsilon^2+\dots)$.